# Можно ли в DatagridView запретить для редактирования все строки кроме последней?

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли в DatagridView запретить для редактирования все строки кроме последней?

Comment: @nick_n_a тут разговор про winforms )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрет на редактирования ячейки :

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].ReadOnly=true;
```

Запрет на редактирования строки:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].ReadOnly=true;
```

Comment: Если 500 строк? Диапазон можно указать?

Comment: Загнать в цикл for(int i = 1; i < count; i++){...}

Comment: Вариант рабочий. Проще открыть для редактирования одну строку, чем лопатить все.

Comment: Возможность редактирования ставиться у грида, так что для открытия возможности редактировать любую строку необходимо открыть все строки.. а так уже решать что именно можно изменять.. Если найдете другой способ, то обязательно напиши в комментарий